# Как подсчитать, сколько элементов в двух множествах совпадают?

Tags: c++, множества, set

Есть два множества set. Нужно подсчитать, сколько элементов из этих множеств совпадают. К элементам множества нельзя обратиться так как к элементам массива или вектора. Значит, c помощью цикла это сделать не получится. Как это сделать иначе?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int count = 0;
string a;
string b;
set<string> a1;
set<string> b1;

void Check(set<string> a, set<string> b)
{
   for(int k = 0; k< size(a); k++)
       for(int q = 0; q<size(b); q++)
       {
           if(a[k] == b[q])
               count = count+1;
       }
}
int main() {
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    for(int i = 0; i< size(a); i++)
    {
        a1.insert(a[i]);
    }
    for(int j = 0; j<size(b); j++)
    {
        b1.insert(b[j]);
    }
    Check(a1, b1);

    return 0;
}
```

Это мой код(неправильный, потому что неправильно обращаюсь к элементам множеств). Пользователь вводит две строки, эти строки вводятся в множества, а потом элементы сравниваются, подсчитывается количество равных элементов. Как сделать это правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Вот так вот:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::set a = {1, 3, 5, 7}, 
                   b = {1, 3, 9, 4};

    std::vector<int> intersection;

    std::set_intersection(std::cbegin(a), std::cend(a),
                          std::cbegin(b), std::cend(b),
                          std::back_inserter(intersection));
    
    std::cout << intersection.size() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь алгоритмом [`set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Answer (score 0):

Почему  же с помощью цикла не получится? Цикл по любому должен иметь место в том или ином алгоритме. Напишем свою функцию, вернувшую количество одинаковых элементов:

```
using std::set;
using std::string;
const unsigned
solution(const set<string>& a1, const set<string>& a2)
{
    unsigned count = 0;
    auto first1 = a1.begin(), first2 = a2.begin();
    while (first1 != a1.end() && first2 != a2.end()) 
    {
        if (*first1 < *first2) {
            ++first1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (*first1 == *first2) {
                ++count;
                ++first1;
            }
            ++first2;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Еще один вариант решения.**
Если первое множество можно модифицировать, и для задачи удобно объединение, то  при объединении можно считать сколько элементов  совпадают, т.е. сколько элементов из второго множества не добавились в первое. Метод: `emplace` какраз возвращает пару итератор и bool, информирующий был ли вставлен объект?

```
const unsigned
solution2(set<string>& a1, const set<string>& a2 )
{
    unsigned count = 0;
    for (auto It = a2.begin(); It != a2.end(); ++It) 
    {
        //если вставлен, ничего не делаем                  
        if (a1.emplace(*It).second)
            continue;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```